# Can the Growl update message be stopped without removing Growl?

Tags: growl

I've recently migrated to Mountain Lion. Every now and then I get a Growl notification saying that a new version of Growl is available. The new version is a paid app, which I don't want to buy, but I can't find a way to disable the update message. It's particularly annoying because unlike a normal Growl notification, this one doesn't go away until you explicitly close it.

If there isn't a way to disable this intrusive advert I will simply remove Growl from my system - but this would be a shame as the current version is still somewhat useful. (Not every program I use supports the new message centre.) So does anybody know of a way to disable this specific message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Growl FAQ](http://growl.info/documentation/faq-new.php) page:

> **How do I disable the update checker in 1.2.2 and below?**
>
> The update checker in Growl 1.2.2 and below will run automatically every 24 hours. The update checker in 1.2.2 admittedly is not great, and is one of the reasons that Growl is now in the App Store.
>
> For those who wish to continue to run Growl 1.2.2, you can do so but will likely benefit from disabling the update checker.
>
> To disable the update checker, follow these steps:
>   - Open System Preferences
>   - Click on Growl
>   - Click on the About tab at the top
>   - Please make sure that you are using 1.2.2. If you are not, please update to 1.2.2 available [here](http://growl.info/downloads)
>   - Uncheck "Check for updates automatically"
>   - Close System Preferences, you are done

Since the older version is going to become less compatible over time I would honestly suggest just paying the $4 and upgrading to the latest version that integrates all Growl notifications into message centre, even for apps that don't support message centre.

Comment: Many thanks! I don't think I'll be upgrading though - by the time compatibility with the old version becomes an issue, most apps will support the notification centre anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I just met this issue too.  I downloaded and built version 2.1.1 using Xcode 4.6.3; this took a while as I needed to download/install a number of applications first (Xcode, command-line tools, Mercurial etc) and follow the build instructions carefully. Being a software developer it wasn't too hard, but it took me much more than $3.99 worth of time to do it.  It was interesting though. If it is compatible with the licence terms, I would consider distributing my build for free: does anyone know if that is legitimate?